# Cómo agregar 3 ceros consecutivos entre cada valor del array ([1,2,3,4,5]) en python

Tags: python, array, numpy

Cómo agregar 0 ceros seguidos al array ([1,2,3,4,5]), o sea, que quede así: `([1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0...])`

Esto es lo que tengo, pero me da error: `'int' object has no attribute 'append'`

```py
    a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    b = np.zeros([1, 3])
    for i in range(1):
       c = i.append(b)
       print(c)
```

Comment: Tienes problemas de identación en tu código. En Python, la identación importa. Saludos

Comment: ahi dice cual es el error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una alternativa es formar la lista usando Python y después crear el arreglo con numpy:

```
import numpy as np

arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5]
nuevo = []
for x in arreglo:
    nuevo.extend([x, 0, 0, 0])
print(nuevo)
c = np.array(nuevo)
print(c)
```

produce:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
[1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 5 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Solución de una línea:

```
np.array([[n, 0,0,0] for n in a]).flatten()
```

Se trata de usar una sintaxis de *comprensión de listas* para crear una lista compuesta por las sub-listas `[n,0,0,0]`, siendo `n` cada uno de los valores de `a`. La lista resultante se pasa a `np.array()` que creará un array bidimensional (pues son listas de listas), que después "aplanamos" con `.flatten()` para dejarlo de nuevo unidimensional como querías.

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu respuesta para examinar las otras respuestas en términos de creación/eliminación de arreglos/listas, adición de elementos y performance en general?

Comment: No entiendo bien qué me pides (en especial eso de "en términos de creación/eliminación de arreglos/listas"). Lo de la performance supongo que bastaría un "timeit". Si prefieres, en vez de explicármelo, puedes añadirlo tú en tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

La variable i es de tipo entero, por lo tanto no tiene método append. Los numpy arrays tampoco lo tienen este método. Pudieras usar la función insert de Numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.zeros(3)
for i in range(0, len(a) * len(b), len(b) + 1):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        a = np.insert(a, i + 1, b[j])
print(a)
```